# Поиск в GridControl с texbox Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

У меня есть textbox и GridControl. Я хочу сделать фильтр, для поиска в GridControl

мой код, но он не работает

```
   private void FilterCollection()
    {
        if (_txtSearch != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_txtSearch))
            {
                ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(DataT);
                view.Filter = new Predicate<object>(UserFilter);
            }
        }
    }



    private bool UserFilter(object item)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_txtSearch))
            return true;
        else
            return ((item as DataText).Discription.IndexOf(_txtSearch, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
    }



    #region Properties

    private string _txtSearch;
    public string TxtSearch
    {
        get { return _txtSearch; }
        set
        {
            _txtSearch = value;
            OnPropertyChange("TxtSearch");
            FilterCollection();
        }
    }
```

Помогите разобраться как это сделать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ViewModel:

```
 public class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private IEnumerable<string> DataT = new String[] { "111", "222", "333", "444", "555", "123", "456" };
    public ICollectionView View { get; set; }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        View = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(DataT);
        View.Filter = o => TxtSearch == null || ((string) o).Contains(TxtSearch);
    }

    private string _txtSearch;
    public string TxtSearch
    {
        get { return _txtSearch; }
        set
        {
            _txtSearch = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            View.Refresh();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <wpfApplication6:ViewModel></wpfApplication6:ViewModel>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding TxtSearch, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding View}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: а можно тут же добавить фильтр, только по дате, у меня есть сделанный но он не работает в мести с этим который Вы мне написали, работають только по отдельности

Comment: можно добавить фильтрацию по дате в том же фильтре. Тогда у вас должна быть коллекция объектов со свойствами Text и Date и фильтр будет выглядеть примерно так `((Item) o).Text.Contains(TxtSearch) && ((Item) o).Date.Contains(DateSearch);`

Comment: если мне нужно с....по дату, то мне нужно написать  `((Item)o).TimeData.Contains(FromDate) && ((Item)o).TimeData.Contains(ToDate);`

Answer (score 0):

да я был близко

```
 public TextViewModel()
    {

        View = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(DataT);
        View.Filter = new Predicate<object>(Filter);


    }

    public bool Filter(object obj)
    {
        var data = obj as DataText;
        if (data != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_txtSearch))
            {
                return data.Discription.Contains(_txtSearch);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```